# PostgreSQL pulling the MAX value from a set of data

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have the following query:

```
SELECT user_id,
greatest(created_at),
note
FROM user_notes
```

Which outputs

```
user_id     greatest            latest_note
12345       2012-09-05             note1
23456       2013-09-01             note2
23456       2013-09-02             note3
etc.              etc.              etc.
```

I thought this query would eliminate duplicates from the user_id  row. I want each user_id to only have one "greatest" result. I can't seem to figure out why there are multiple "greatests" for the same user_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `MAX()` not `GREATEST()`:

```
WITH latest AS (
   SELECT user_id, max(created_at) AS created_at
   FROM user_notes
   GROUP BY user_id)
SELECT user_notes.*
FROM user_notes
INNER JOIN latest
USING (user_id, created_at)
```